# Visual Studio 2015 c# new keyword creates redundant qualifiers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Whenever I use the new keyword the Visual Studio autocomplete adds a redundant namespace qualifier that I have to remove manually every time.
Example:
Statistics stats = new NNF.Statistics();

NNF. is redundant. Is there any way I can turn this off?
I also use Resharper but I dont think it is related.

Comment: It is redundant because you use `using NNF;`. How about when you use `Statistics stats = new Statistics();`

Comment: It is redundant because NNF is the single namespace of my Project.

Comment: @GSP: I am not sure you understand the question... because that comment doesn't make any sense